# Actions an ORM does behind the scenes

Tags: java, php, hibernate, orm, doctrine-orm

I would like to know what an ORM does behind the scene for each of the following actions:

```
 1. $obj = new className(); // creating new Object
 2. $bj->setMethod('value'); // setting a value to it
 3. $obj->getMethod(); // getting the value which was already set
 4. $obj->save(); // saving the object
```

My question is not specific to one particular ORM, it's open to all popular ones.

Comment: ORMs in general, or Hibernate? I don't think Hibernate does anything "behind the scenes" when you get/set on the entity or create a new one. And "save" is different than "update", although there is a "saveOrUpdate".

Comment: I think you should look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159494/behind-the-scenes-how-does-an-orm-think, hope this will be able to give you some depth, you are looking for.

Comment: Since you tagged it as Doctrine 2 then I'll answer for it.  For items 1,2,3, Doctrine does nothing.  For item 4, there is no save method on entities.  Might want to look the difference between active record and data mappers.

Comment: I see.. presently, I'm working with PROPEL in which I do - $obj->save(); to save the changes to DB..! Guys, any thought on this.